# R: Post requests to HTTP servers

Tags: r, curl, post, http-headers, http-post

Which is the equivalent of cURL command option  `--data`  using the R [library](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl) `curl`?

For example:

```
curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST ...

curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST ...
```

Note that here I am interested specifically to 
[curl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl) library. There are packages  more high levels (httr) or not maintained (RCurl).

It would be also nice if someone with privileges could add a tag for the [curl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl) library, as it is a dependency for most R web libraries.

Comment: Might it be `h <- new_handle(); 
handle_setform(h, key1 = "value1", key2 = "value2")` ?

Comment: Or maybe `form_data("value1", type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`